# Abintio Record Format- Setting NULL to variable

Tags: ab-initio

I have a compoents input record format with a field set to NULL,
like,

```
record

string(3) INPUT = NULL;

end;
```

Comp A -----FlowAtoB---------> Comp B

The above record format is the FlowAtoB.
I can understand that this sets the value of INPUT to null. But, In case if i have value for this from previous component A, how this will behave?

I'm not able to understand clearly the use of this from the help document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default setting for your INPUT.
There is nothing wrong with it.
When component A will send the information to B it will behave just fine, as far as I'm concerned.

Look at this example from my grpah that I'm working right now:

```
string(30) salesperson = NULL("");
```

When I send data it works ok.

Try adding the brackets and quotation marks, but I think it was by default there.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Marcin. So, in case that particular field like your salesperson has a value from previous component. The value is same here in my next one. In case, the field is empty, it'll replace a null. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly as I understand it, and it works for me.